# Load a view file in a not ordinary way using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, view

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know if it is possible to use a namespaced URL to filter data.

For example, I have a namespace stated like this:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :accounts
end
```

Using the above code I can access account data with id `1` at the URL (this load the `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/users/accounts/show.html.erb` file)

```
http://localhost/users/accounts/2
```

What I would like to do is to browse the following URL

```
http://realer.com/users/2
```

in order to load a view named `supervision.html.erb` located in the main folder of `users`:

```
`RAILS_ROOT/app/views/users/supervision.html.erb` # This is the file that I would like to load

`RAILS_ROOT/app/views/users/accounts/new.html.erb`
`RAILS_ROOT/app/views/users/accounts/show.html.erb`
...
```

I thinked to approach like that because I would like to have separated views for each action and then incorporate all of them as partial views in a single file, in my case `supervision.html.erb`. Doing that I don't have to change, for example, the `show.html.erb` file individually so that I can keep this view file "untouched"\"pure" with the possibility of load that in other views. That is, the `show.html.erb` must be used to do one only thing, so in that must be not loaded other partials.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the view file itself that you're wanting to render differently, and the URL structure doesn't really matter as much to you you can do this in the controller:

```
def show
  render 'users/supervision'
end
```

If you *really* want to change the URL structure too ... I'm not sure if there's a shortcut way of doing it but you can always do this:

```
match 'users/:id' => 'accounts#show'
```

Or

```
match 'users/:id' => 'users/accounts#show'
```